# Batch write to DynamoDB [Java]

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am reading a csv file and want to write multiple lines at once to DynamoDB. Is there a way to do this. 
I have found an example in AWS documentation but it doesn't serve the purpose at we need to do it manually.

```
private static void testBatchSave(DynamoDBMapper mapper) {

Book book1 = new Book();
book1.id = 901;
book1.inPublication = true;
book1.ISBN = "902-11-11-1111";
book1.pageCount = 100;
book1.price = 10;
book1.productCategory = "Book";
book1.title = "My book created in batch write";

Book book2 = new Book();
book2.id = 902;
book2.inPublication = true;
book2.ISBN = "902-11-12-1111";
book2.pageCount = 200;
book2.price = 20;
book2.productCategory = "Book";
book2.title = "My second book created in batch write";

Book book3 = new Book();
book3.id = 903;
book3.inPublication = false;
book3.ISBN = "902-11-13-1111";
book3.pageCount = 300;
book3.price = 25;
book3.productCategory = "Book";
book3.title = "My third book created in batch write";

System.out.println("Adding three books to ProductCatalog table.");
mapper.batchSave(Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3));
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use **batch save** and construct the objects to be saved pro-grammatically. There is no tool like **mongoimport** to import the file directly.

However, you can use [AWS data pipeline service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-part1.html) to import the data into DynamoDB tables.

Comment: I want to do this in a lambda Function, is there a way to link the pipeline to lambda function ?